# link_to delete not working in rails 4?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I am upgrading my rails application to rails 4. After upgrading delete method was not working. When I check the log its printing as get method.

```
code :view file:
<%= link_to image_tag("/images/iconDeleteActive.png", :alt=>"Delete",:border=>"0", :title=>'Delete'),client_admin_property_path    (user_id,property.id,:sort => params[:sort] || 'Commercial'),:method=>:delete %>

routes:
 scope :module => "client_admin"  do
    resources :client_admin do
    resources :properties
    end
    end

log:
Started GET "/client_admin/61/properties/5126?sort=Commercial"
AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'show' could not be found for ClientAdmin::PropertiesController:
```

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing :method to 'data-method'